# How to set Plugin Header image on wordpress.org

Tags: wordpress

I have developed a plugin for school project to parent login/register and uploaded on WordPress plugin directory, but i am not able to sat banner image on top.
Please guide me if have any idea.

Comment: When you say you can not "set banner image on top" . What you tried, whats happening and what you expected ?

Comment: I want to set  banner image like this plugin have used.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/slideshow-jquery-image-gallery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this link. You will find your solution.

**Source:** https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-assets/

Answer (score 0):

To Add a Plugin Header Image:

Make a 772×250 pixel JPG or PNG image file. (No animated GIFs. :) )
Check it in to your plugin’s SVN directory with the path assets/banner-772x250.(jpg|png). Note that the assets directory is added to your plugin’s root directory, not trunk.
On the next plugin directory refresh (every 15 minutes or so) you should see your image start showing up on the page.
For an example of this in action, check out Hello Dolly or Pluginception for HiDPI action.

You can also make larger images, which will be used on high-DPI displays (aka ‘retina’). To do so, make a second image with the size of 1544 pizels wide and 500 pixels high. This file will be named assets/banner-1544x500.(jpg|png). Note that you can not make this image alone, it only works as an “add-on” to the 772×250 image, because this larger image is only used on displays that can show the higher detail.

To add a plugin header image in the new directory:

Make a 1880×609 pixel JPG or PNG image file. (No animated GIFs. :) )
Check it in to your plugin’s SVN directory with the path assets/banner-1880x609.(jpg|png). Note that the assets directory is added to your plugin’s root directory, not trunk.
On the next plugin directory refresh (every 15 minutes or so) you should see your image start showing up on the page.
Unlike the old plugin directory, no other plugin banner is required.

Another thing to consider is the case for the international plugin directories. Some of these, like Hebrew and Arabic, use Right-To-Left languages. In these cases, the title will be overlaid on the right hand side of the image, not on the left side. Generally it is best to design your banner such that the title can be in either position. However, this may not work with all designs, so if you need to have a different image for RTL pages, then you can do so. Make the images in the same way as before, but name them with -rtl appended to the name. So an RTL banner would be named assets/banner-772x250-rtl.(jpg|png) and assets/banner-1544x500-rtl.(jpg|png) or assets/banner-1880x609-rtl.(jpg|png) for the new directory. On RTL pages, if these images are available, then they will be displayed instead.

After you check in your new banner(s), it will appear the next time the plugin refreshes itself in the directory. This may take a few minutes.

For development and testing, you can add a URL parameter to your plugin’s URL of ?banner_url=A_URL_TO_YOUR_IMAGE to preview what the page will look like with your own image. This will only work with your own plugins; you cannot use this parameter on anybody else’s plugins.

Comment: I have follow this instruction. But i was not able to successfully set banner image. Please give me another help full tutorial.